# What Does Tensorflow.js Use fbjs For?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, fbjs

I was looking over the Tensorflow.js dependencies and noticed that `fbjs` is included in the dependency list. What functionality requires `fbjs`? I'm not familiar with the package, but I'm aware that it is a Facebook JavaScript package. It just seems a little strange to me, but as I said, I don't know much about `fbjs` so maybe there's something useful in the context of Tensorflow.js.

Comment: Why does it seem strange ? The package contains several dependencies. Why would this one in particular seem strange ?

Comment: Facebook is one of the largest, if not the largest, social media companies. I just thought it was weird. Evidently, the package includes visual tools which tfjs-vis uses so it makes sense. When I see a Facebook JavaScript package, the first thing that comes to mind is social media integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook JavaScript package, `fbjs`, used in Tensorflow.js is for the `tfjs-vis` package. `fbjs` contains several visual tools utilized in `tfjs-vis`.

Being that Facebook is most known as a social media platform, I found it odd at the time.